# Why this second part of the integral given by the gradient of the log-likelihood is zero

Tags: delay, maximum-likelihood-estimation

I am reading the book "Detection of Signals in Noise" by Robert N McDonough, A D Whalen. In chapter 10, they compute the gradient of the log-likelihood for the time of arrival. See attached picture.

I do not understand why the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{-T/2}^{T/2} m(t-\hat{\tau}) \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{\tau}} m(t-\hat{\tau}) dt
\end{equation}
is identically zero, as the authors state?

I could not find any special assumptions on the delayed signal $m$ that would help clarify why that could hold.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because
$$
m(t) = A \cos(\omega_c t + \phi)
$$
and $T$ is a single period of the cosine (or an integer multiple of the period).

Then
$$
\frac{d}{d t}\left(A \cos(\omega_c t + \phi)\right) = -A\omega_c \sin(\omega_c t + \phi)
$$
so that the integral is zero.

But you'd have to tell me more about $m(t)$ from the text book before we could be sure.